# Adding a clamp to the rotation of a 2D object in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working for a long time trying to get a clamp implemented on my 2D object in Unity2D. I have struggled with this issue for weeks now. I have a rocketship that moves upwards on it's own, and I'm trying to make it where you can't go further than 40 degrees rotating. Some details to note is that the ship rotates(x-axis of course) and moves toward the mouse(x-axis, doesn't go further up more then the current velocity) as a way to avoid obstacles which are coming soon. Here's my code for the ship:

```
public class MiniGameRocketShipController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(0f, 1500f);

    private Vector2 directionX;
    private Vector2 directionY;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public new Camera camera;

    public float moveSpeed = 100f;
    public float rotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        rotation = rb.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionX.x * moveSpeed, directionY.y * moveSpeed);

        FaceMouse();
    }

    void FaceMouse()
    {
        if (rotation > 180)
        {
            rotation = 360;
        }

        rotation = Mathf.Clamp(rotation, -40f, 40f);
        rb.rotation = rotation;

        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        directionX = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;
        directionY = transform.position.normalized;

        transform.up = directionX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vector2.SignedAngle` and `Mathf.Clamp` to do this. Explanation in comments:

```
// world direction to clamp to as the origin
Vector2 clampOriginDirection = Vector2.up;

// what local direction should we compare to the clamp origin
Vector2 clampLocalDirection = Vector2.up;

// how far can the local direction stray from the origin
float maxAbsoluteDeltaDegrees = 40f;

void ClampDirection2D()
{ 
    // world direction of the clamped local
    // could be `... = transform.up;` if you are ok hardcoding comparing local up 
    Vector2 currentWorldDirection = transform.TransformDirection(clampLocalDirection);

    // how far is it from the origin?
    float curSignedAngle = Vector2.SignedAngle(clampOriginDirection, currentWorldDirection);

    // clamp that angular distance
    float targetSignedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(curSignedAngle, -maxAbsoluteDeltaDegrees,
            maxAbsoluteDeltaDegrees);

    // How far is that from the current signed angle?
    float targetDelta = targetSignedAngle - curSignedAngle;

    // apply that delta to the rigidbody's rotation:
    rb.rotation += targetDelta;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Where do you call the function at? Is it Update or Start?

Comment: @Concepts I would call it at the end of `Update`. It will work wherever you need it, though, as long as `rb` is defined. You just need to make sure you don't overwrite any of its changes to `rb.rotation` before the frame is drawn, unless you really mean to do that.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this in a second. Are you using RigidBody2D or 3D? This is a 2D Game. Also, do you need to change the clampOriginDirection and the clampLocalDirection? Just wondering. So far my code hasn't worked.

Comment: The code you put in the question defines `public Rigidbody2D rb;`, so that's what I wrote in this answer. And you say that you want to clamp the local `up` to something within 30 degrees of global `up`, so I would leave `clampLocalDirection` and `clampOriginDirection` to `Vector2.up` as they are here.

Comment: I still haven't managed to get this to work. Thank you for trying though. I really appreciate it.